# Change datatype of range of columns while importing a CSV file

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, python-window, column

Let's say I have a `CSV` file that has a bunch of columns, starting from `Field1` to `Field141`. Now all these columns have a `text` datatype. And I would like to import this CSV in such a way that the datatypes of columns `Field3` to `Field141` are changed to a numeric datatype when saved as a `dbf` in `ArcGIS Pro 3.1`.

How can I do this in ArcGIS Pro 3.1 Python console window?

Current approach:

1. Use the `Table to Geodatabase` tool to import the CSV file as a `dbf` table.
2. Try to write some code in the Python console window that can change the datatype of the desired columns. (Based on the comment, this is not the right approach)

Current code:

```
# Get the list field names 
AllFieldNames = [Field.name for Field in arcpy.ListFields('us_county_deaths_cases', 'Field*')]

# Stuck on how to then use this list with maybe as.type to change their datatype to numeric
```

Comment: You can't change the datatype of the fields of an existing feature class. You need to create a new table with the desired properties, then insert into that while casting the datatypes.

Comment: Is it the same for a datatable (a CSV file imported as a table) too?

Comment: The act of importing changes the data storage and makes it fixed. You'd need to regenerate the tables imported with different rules. It's probably a toss-up as to which is easier.

Comment: I know I can use the `Export Table` tool to do this manually but that would be tedious as I will have to change the datatype of each column one by one. So if it's not much to ask then can you please guide me with a coding approach (which I believe would be the quicker way of doing this) using the Python console window in ArcGIS Pro 3.1 in an answer?

Comment: You don't need to change the field type, just process the result you get back in the DA cursor.  The part where that happens is much later in the Answer code (and not provided).

Comment: Can you please explain `just process the result you get back in the DA cursor`  further in an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can explicitly set the col & field types of the CSV by creating a schema.ini . Then you could just use CopyRows to take the .csv as input and write out the .dbf.

this bit of python code

```
with open("schema_to_be_renamed.ini", 'w') as outf:
    outf.writelines("[my_csv_name]\r\n")
    for i in range(3, 6):
        outf.writelines(f"Col{i}=ColName{i} Double\r\n")
```

will produces a schema_to_be_renamed.ini file, update it until it matches your needs . Then you'd want to change the [my_csv_name], rename schema_to_be_renamed.ini to schema.ini, and put it in the folder with your .csv , then run CopyRows on the data and see what comes out.

#### reference

- https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/data/tables/add-an-ascii-or-text-file-table.htm
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/microsoft/schema-ini-file-text-file-driver?view=sql-server-ver16